# State Machine Workflow With ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow-foundation

I'm very new to the MVC development environment. Can anyone direct me to the necessay resources or provide me a sample code which uses State Machine Workflow to control the views (navigate between views).

Comment: why do you think you need that?

Comment: There is a reason why there are no examples available. Because it makes no sense to control views through SMW. Just read tutorials on MVC. Start here http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight

Comment: See my last posted answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the RedirectToAction method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx

Once your workflow determines what action needs to be executed, call that method and the browser will be redirected and control moved to that action. On the other hand, if you just need to present a specific view, you can just use the controller's View method and pass in the name of the view you want to show:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx